# How to build multi-arch snaps

Tags: ubuntu-core, snap

I've got a snap that I'd like to build for multiple architectures. Right now, in the `snapcraft.yaml` file I define a wrapper as the binary to execute, which sets up environment variables required for the app to run.

One piece of script code that it contains is the following:

```
#!/bin/sh
ARCH='x86_64-linux-gnu'
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$SNAP/usr/lib/$ARCH:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Obviously, hardcoding `ARCH` is not optimal, as non-amd64 builds will not work correctly. However, arch detection using `dpkg-architecture` will not work when using Snapcraft.

How can I dynamically detect the host's architecture in my wrapper to set the correct library paths while building the snap with Snapcraft?

Code is available as part of the [snappy desktop examples](http://bazaar.launchpad.net/~snappers/snappy-desktop-examples/trunk/files/head:/ubuntu-clock-app).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The binary wrappers (and service files) define the `SNAP_ARCH` environment variable for you. Unfortunately not an ideal solution since they're not triplets, but it should be enough information for you to get there with a case statement or something.

Answer (score 1):

For the sake of completeness, I ended up using the following shell snippet:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

case "$SNAP_ARCH" in
    "amd64") ARCH='x86_64-linux-gnu'
    ;;
    "i386") ARCH='i386-linux-gnu'
    ;;
    *)
        echo "Unsupported architecture for this clock app build"
        exit 1
    ;;
esac
```

However, as the wrapper starts getting complicated, I'm rather looking at [creating a Snapcraft plugin](https://snapcraft.io/docs/build-snaps/plugins) instead.

Comment: The link to the Snapcraft plugin docs is a 404. You probably want [this one](https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/snappy/build-apps/plugins/). I'd edit, but it's not enough characters :P .